# NUnit used for integration tests with a class library

Tags: c#, .net, testing, .net-3.5, nunit

I am new to NUnit, but for time constraints on an old project, I am doing some quick integration tests.  I have created a test database to test against, but how do I connect to it?

My NUnit project is a class library, and that can't have a web.config or app.config to pull the connection string from. Do I change it to a web project or some application project (it's just a class library now) or is there some why to connect to the database in the NUnit code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact your test project CAN have an app.config file. NUnit will load it correctly.

http://blog.coryfoy.com/2005/08/nunit-app-config-files-its-all-about-the-nunit-file/

This might also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5821939/1373170

Comment: cool +1, i'll have to check on this tomorrow morning at work!