# Unit-tests can't read from config files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nunit, integration-testing, app-config

We have a setup where we use Visual Studio 2012 to run our nunit-based unit tests from our local dev environments.

However, we have observed the following pattern:

1. When running unit tests the first time after Visual Studio has been
   launched, the tests fail when reading from config-files.
2. When rerunning the failing unit tests they can read the values from
       config files just fine.

This is truly a little bit annoying so I was hoping for a bit of help here :-).

I looked at [Problem in reading connection string from App.Config when using NUnit 2.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633607/problem-in-reading-connection-string-from-app-config-when-using-nunit-2-5-2/5821939#5821939) , but since we run our unit tests directly in Visual Studio, there is no way for us to configure NUnit directly.

Comment: Do you use the standard configuration files (i.e. aplicationname.exe.config) or custom config files - and if so, how do you find the correct location of the files (your application may have been copied to some strange place for the unit tests!)?

Comment: No custom config files. My test project is of type "Class library" with an added app.config file in it.

Comment: Just note that if your tests need configuration to run, they are not Unit Tests. They are integration tests.

Comment: @Raj haha yes - that is true :-). Doesn't make my problem any less annoying, though.

Comment: Strange I'm using VS2012 Test runner, NUnit 2.6.2.12296, reading an App.config file. No issues. Works every time. Are able to test this with a latest version of NUnit 2.6.2.12296v? Also what happens if you create a new class library with an App.config, are you running to the same issue?

Comment: i'm having this issue today, running VS2013, NUnit 2.6.2.12296, Resharper 8.2.0.2160 test runner. My config reading is actually occurring in my app, not the units tests. Running the unit test for the standalone project passes. Running all unit tests for solution ( 3 projects), config reading fails

Answer (score 0):

NUnit looks for the configuration file in the wrong position, and does not ifnd the config file. Look at

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase
```

and

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = configFile }, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

to get the correct location.